# How to fix AttributeError: 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute 'data' on mmdetection?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to set up mm-detection for custom datasets at the moment and have consistently hit these errors. I have tried getting rid of the def functions in the code, have change file locations and all of the above. I have no idea what is wrong with the code and why it is not working.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from mmdet.apis import init_detector, inference_detector
import mmcv
from mmdet.apis import (async_inference_detector, inference_detector,
                        init_detector, show_result_pyplot)
import asyncio
import torch
from mmdet.apis import init_detector, async_inference_detector
from mmdet.utils.contextmanagers import concurrent

def data():
# The new config inherits a base config to highlight the necessary modification
    base_ = 'configs/mask_rcnn/mask_rcnn_r50_caffe_fpn_1x_coco.py'

# We also need to change the num_classes in head to match the dataset's annotation
# dict is a python dictionary object which is used to save or load models from PyTorch
    model = dict(
        roi_head=dict(
        # defining the number of classes a bounding box can go around
            bbox_head=dict(num_classes=1),
            # 
            mask_head=dict(num_classes=1)))

def dataset():
    # Modify dataset related settings
    dataset_type = 'COCODataset'
    #Defining the classes
    classes = ('Pantograph')
    data = dict(
        train=dict(
            img_prefix='testing/',
            classes=classes,
            ann_file='train/Pan2_COCO.json'),
        val=dict(
            img_prefix='testing/',
            classes=classes,
            ann_file='val/Pan2_COCO.json'),
        test=dict(
            img_prefix='testing/',
            classes=classes,
            ann_file='val/Pan2_COCO.json'))
def load():
# We can use the pre-trained Mask RCNN model to obtain higher performance
    load_from = 'testing/checkpoints/mask_rcnn_r50_caffe_fpn_mstrain-poly_3x_coco_bbox_mAP-0.408__segm_mAP-0.37_20200504_163245-42aa3d00.pth'

data()
dataset()
load()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 244, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 135, in main
    setup_multi_processes(cfg)
  File "/home/dtl-admin/dev/mmdetection/mmdet/utils/setup_env.py", line 30, in setup_multi_processes
    workers_per_gpu = cfg.data.get('workers_per_gpu', 1)
  File "/home/dtl-admin/miniconda3/envs/mmtest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv/utils/config.py", line 519, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._cfg_dict, name)
  File "/home/dtl-admin/miniconda3/envs/mmtest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv/utils/config.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    raise ex
AttributeError: 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I was expecting an output where the image detects the class pantograph. However, I cannot get any output no matter what I try and I have tried changing as many variables as possible.

Comment: This is more of a question for the issues page. e.g., see [this issue](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection3d/issues/1254)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the original error it was to do with the dataset not being in the Coco format. I did tell my manager and colleague this multiple times but they didn't listen. If you also have this error I recommend labelling with Label studio as when I export using their coco format it actually works without any modifications.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your config file it definitely shouldn't include definitions, mmDetection has a great example of a mask rcnn config file here: https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/v2.28.1/tutorials/config.html

You can pretty much copy it and change the ann_file attributes to point to your data.

You can then load this config file into your test file and train your model. This notebook I've been using:
https://notebook.community/open-mmlab/mmdetection/demo/MMDet_Tutorial
has a good step by step tutorial (though its a little out of date) for how to go about it. You can cross reference with the first link to make sure you have the right updates.